# Scripting - Folders with spaces

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting

I'm trying to write a script that's robust enough to work with spaces.

Its currently in a for loop, but the problem I'm having is folders with spaces in its name.

```
ASOURCE="Home Photos 2012 camcorder" #example filename
if [ -d "$(echo $ASOURCE)" ] # If directory exists
then
#command
else
echo "File does not exist: " $1 #Error
echo "DIR :" $(echo $ASOURCE | sed 's/\ /\\ /g')
fi
```

It fails on the the verification. I've tried pre-escaping the spaces, but to no avail

Comment: First, replace `"$(echo $ASOURCE)"` with `"$ASOURCE"`, if it doesn't work, at least, it will look nicer. :-)

Comment: well, it looks nicer :P

Comment: What shell are you using? This works exactly as expected in bash. Are you actually trying to run this by passing the directory name as an argument? Are you maybe doing this without quoting it?

Answer (score 2):

You should **always**(*) quote your variables, particularly if they contain arbitrary user input.

In this case, if you're scripting with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), use double brackets so you don't need to quote (bash is smart that way), and use `printf "%q"` to get bash to escape what needs to be escaped:

```
ASOURCE="Home Photos 2012 camcorder" #example filename
if [[ -d $ASOURCE ]]; then
    # directory exists
    :
else
    # Note how these vars are quoted:
    echo "File does not exist:  $1"
    printf "DIR : %q\n" "$ASOURCE"
fi
```

(*) except when you know *exactly* when you don't want to quote them.